# SSL chain verification problems

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, godaddy

I've installed a new SSL certificate using SHA2 hashing instead of SHA1.  My chain checks out using these online verifiers:

- http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
- http://www.digicert.com/help/

However this one tells me it can't find the Root CA:

- http://www.geocerts.com/ssl_checker

How do I fix this?

Edit:  Derp, here's the URL:  secure.symt.us

This is on Apache2 on CentOS.

I have followed GoDaddy's setup instructions to the letter and restarted the server.

Edit 2, apache vhost conf:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2.crt
```

==== [SOLVED] ====

The problem turned out to be that my vhost was defined as `<VirtualHost *:443>`.  Changing it to the server's IP address `<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>` fixed it.

There was a catch-all default `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` albeit without an SSLCertificateChainFile directive.  Grepping /etc/httpd for SSLCertificateChainFile returned only my directive.

Perhaps apache has its own default SSLCertificateChainFile internally and refused to send mine when configured as *:443?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the certificate chain. Follow [GoDaddy's Instructions](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7), make sure you install their Intermediate certificates (commonly called a chain, or bundle as well)

[GoDaddy supports Internet Censorship](https://www.google.com/search?q=GoDaddy+SOPA). You should seriously reconsider funding them. Especially when you can get [SSL Certificates for Free](http://startssl.com).

---

For Apache 2.2.x, you need all three of the following (for a standard configuration)

```
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/public/key_file
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private/key_file
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain/file
```

You're likely missing that last one.

Comment: I've followed their instructions to the letter and I still have the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: Hi Chris, Apache 2 on CentOS, not IIS.

Comment: See edit. Post your SSL* configuration lies if that's not the case.

Comment: vhost conf posted.

Comment: Must have the wrong chain file: https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki?streamfilename=gdig2.crt&actionMethod=anonymous%2Frepository.xhtml%3Arepository.streamFile%28%27%27%29&cid=179406  Running `sha1 /path/to/chain/file` should return "C62FE90D242CA64F1FFD82BFCAAC1AEF41BDD21D".

Comment: OK, I've updated the chain directive to point to the correct file (gdig2.crt) and I've verified the sha1 hash and I've restarted the server, and I STILL get the same error from ssllabs.com/ssltest argh.  Chrome is reporting the proper intermediate cert though, what the heck is going on?

Comment: You cleared the cache on SSL labs to be sure you're actually retesting? Chrome has many intermediate certificates built-in, for misconfigured servers. If SSL labs still reports a problem you must have another SSLCertificateChainFile directive somewhere in your configuration. The stock `httpd.conf` in many Linux distros comes with a lot of weird stuff. Running `httpd -S` will dump the whole configuration as Apache sees it; running it through a `grep -i chain` might reveal what's going on.

Comment: Yep, was clearing the cache each time.  So I finally found it:  using httpd -S showed me that there was a _default_ 443 host, although there were no SSLCertificateChainFile rules other than my one.  I remembered having trouble with another SSL server that was using *:443 for the vhost which was resolved by using the IP address.  I changed this vhost to use the server's IP, and now it's reporting OK all the way through.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9202/discussion-between-jemminger-and-chris-s)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not properly configured to send the required intermediate certificate. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/509162/63156) for a more detailed description of why this is a problem, and why you (or even some SSL verifiers) may not notice it during testing.

The missing certificate in your case is http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt.

The [SSL Labs online test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) shows this problem as a warning (and, BTW, finds several other problems with your server configuration).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same trouble, when I see the site with Android the page show an error
of the certificate. 
I test the page with https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
and the chain is broken, after a few tests I use this certificate http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt like intermediate certificate
for this property SSLCertificateChainFile.
All my hosts are configurated with  and 
And this works perfect.

Answer (score -1):

The problem took me hours of work. Had a wildcard certificate from Global Sign; see www.unfallkassesachsn.de. My mistake: configured SSL ... File in vhosts.d.
After doing this in ssl-global.conf I'd got an A from Qualys.